# How do I select a specific row without using a hard coded value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a Q & A website where users can ask software related questions.  On the Question page I have a GridView with radio buttons next to each row.  The idea is that the user selects a radio button, then clicks a button(btnAnswer) at the bottom of the page which transfers them to the answer page.  Using a SESSION, how would I go about selecting that specific question from the database on the Answer page?

Here is a small snippet of my code from the Question page (keep in mind that everything else on this page is working as intended and is designed for only one radio button to be selected at a time):

```
protected void btnAnswer_onClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < grdAnswer.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)grdAnswer.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("rbtnAnswer");
        if (rb.Checked)
        {
            string link = grdAnswer.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text.ToString();
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "open" + i, "window.open('" + link + "');");
        }
    }
    Session["ButtonClicked"] = "btnAnswer";
    Response.Redirect("AnswerQuestion.aspx?tag=" + grdAnswer);
}
```

On the Answer page I need to change my SQL query so I don't have a hard-coded value.  Here is what I have that needs to be changed:

```
// This is part of several if statements and is designed so if the btnAnswer was clicked, it makes this GridView visible
else if (Session["ButtonClicked"] == "btnAnswer") 
{
    grdAnswerFromAsk.Visible = true;
    String connectionString = "Server=test;Database=testdb;User=root;Password=pw";

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        // the next line ID 45 is used and needs to be changed so that whatever radio button was selected, that is the question that displays on the Answer page
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Question FROM Questions WHERE QuestionID = 45");
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't have link instead of radio button? In that link you could put questionid in query string. Then in answer page just grab the id from that query string.

Comment: I think you need to pass the question id to the answer page as a query string or session variable. then use parameterized query and use this id

Comment: So which part are you stuck on? Getting the question ID from the request or putting it into the SQL Query?

Comment: Putting the QuestionID into the query, I don't want it hard coded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to pass the value of the checked radio button to the answer page.
You wrote in your comments that you don't want the user to know what is the question Id associated with the radio button, so here is one solution for that:
Use a `Dictionaty<string, int>` in your first aspx page that will hold the text of the radio button (if it unique) or any other value that is unique to the grid row as key, and the question id as value.
On the `btnAnswer_onClick` method get the question id corresponding to the key of the checked radio button and put it inside a Session variable.
Then all you have to do is get the value from the Session object in the next page.

Second, use a [parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter(v=vs.110).aspx) to specify the value to the sql statement:

```
int CheckedRadioButtonValue = Session["CheckedRadioButtonValue "]; // perhaps a query string would be better here

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Question FROM Questions WHERE QuestionID = @QuestionID");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QuestionID", CheckedRadioButtonValue);
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
}
```

Comment: Alright, yeah I don't know how to pass that checked radio button value.
I am using this:

String questionid = "SELECT QuestionID FROM Questions";
int CheckedRadioButtonValue = Convert.ToInt32(questionid);

On top of the parametized code you gave above.

Comment: I tried  int CheckedRadioButtonValue = Convert.ToInt32("SELECT QuestionID FROM Questions WHERE QuestionID = " + Session["CheckedRadioButtonValue"]); which gives me a FormatException error.

Comment: Do you keep the question id in the radio button or the grid row anywhere?

Comment: No I am not, I don't want the user to see the ID.

Comment: Why are you using a query like the one in your comment above? You are using a query to return the value of your session value. You already know the QuestionID, it is in your session. Querying for that is ridiculous.

Comment: I thought so too but if I try to use Zohar's method with declaring an int I get an error saying "Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: How do you decide what hard coded value to use now?

Comment: Right now I am using @QuestionID in my query.

Comment: Ok,  When it was hard coded as 45, who did you decided that it should be 45 and not some other id?

Comment: I was using 45 as a test to make sure that my code was doing what I wanted.  Now that it is, I want to be able to select any question from that table.

Comment: I see. Well, you will need to send the question id from the radii button to the next page somehow. If you don't want the user to see what it is you can use the session object to do it. I can't write a code example now but maybe tomorow.

Comment: Alright, i will check this thread again tomorrow.  Thank you for the help so far!